# Error al reparar tabla corrupta mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

recientemente tuve un problema con una de las tablas de mi base de datos, cuando ingreso a la base de datos, la tabla en cuestión me aparece "en uso".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado utilizar la opción de reparar tabla, pero aún así no funciona.

Me devuelve el mensaje de error:

```
Información errónea en el archivo '.\mybd\facturas.frm'
Corrupt
```

He buscado por internet pero no he podido encontrar ninguna solución,
estoy usando xampp en windows

Comment: no tengo ni idea de tu problema.. pero estas usando una base mysql, y lo que tenes que arreglar es mysql.. xampp no tiene nada que ver (es solo un empaquetador de cosas) y phpmyadmin es como accedes a tu base de datos (pero podrias acceder de otras formas).

Comment: Amigo, para tu problema hay bastantes soluciones en internet, lo que mas sugieren es que no es una tabla si no una vista. Puedes consultarlo aqui: https://www.kroatoan.es/trucos-y-solucines/error-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine/

Comment: ¿Desde dónde intentaste la reparación, desde PHPMyAdmin o desde la consola? Si tienes acceso a mysql por consola es recomendable para este caso que intentes reparar desde la consola. Sería importante también que nos digas si tu tabla es muy grande (¿tamaño en GB de tu tabla?).

Comment: Intenté realizar la reparación desde la consola, pero la tabla sigue con el mismo problema, y en cuanto al tamaño son aproximadamente unos 50 KB